# How I consume Web Service SOAP in Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I try to consume a WebService SAP (SOAP) in Android Project.

[WebService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t42ii.png)

I use Android Studio with ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1.jar
[ksoap2 library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jKzs.png)

My code is as fallows:

```
public void executeSAPWebService {
    String nameSapceSap = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style";
    String urlSap = "http://localhost:8010/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zconsultamtn/300/zconsultamtn/zconsultamtn";
    String methosSap = "Zconsultamtn";
    String soapActionSap = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style/Zconsultamtn";

    SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(nameSapceSap,methosSap);

    PropertyInfo propertyInfoIean = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfoImatnr = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfoIwerks = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfoUser = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfoPwd = new PropertyInfo();

    propertyInfoUser.setName("username");
    propertyInfoUser.setValue("MyUser");
    propertyInfoUser.setType(String.class);
    soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfoUser);

    propertyInfoPwd.setName("password");
    propertyInfoPwd.setValue("myPwd");
    propertyInfoPwd.setType(String.class);
    soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfoPwd);

    propertyInfoIean.setName("IEan");
    propertyInfoIean.setValue("75010553000075");
    propertyInfoIean.setType(String.class);
    soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfoIean);

    propertyInfoImatnr.setName("IMatnr");
    propertyInfoImatnr.setValue("");
    propertyInfoImatnr.setType(String.class);
    soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfoImatnr);

    propertyInfoIwerks.setName("IMatnr");
    propertyInfoIwerks.setValue("0236");
    propertyInfoIwerks.setType(String.class);
    soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfoIwerks);

    PropertyInfo propertyInfoZmueble = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfoZtramo = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfoZnivel = new PropertyInfo();

    propertyInfoZmueble.setName("Zmueble");
    propertyInfoZmueble.setValue("");
    propertyInfoZmueble.setType(String.class);
    soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfoZmueble);

    propertyInfoZtramo.setName("Ztramo");
    propertyInfoZtramo.setValue("");
    propertyInfoZtramo.setType(String.class);
    soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfoZtramo);

    propertyInfoZnivel.setName("Znivel");
    propertyInfoZnivel.setValue("");
    propertyInfoZnivel.setType(String.class);
    soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfoZnivel);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelopeSap = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelopeSap.dotNet = false;
    envelopeSap.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

    envelopeSap.headerOut = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element[1];
    envelopeSap.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader();

    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(urlSap);

    List<HeaderProperty> c = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    c.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization","Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));

    try {
        final Object responde = httpTransportSE.call(soapActionSap,envelopeSap,c);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelopeSap.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private org.kxml2.kdom.Element buildAuthHeader() {
    org.kxml2.kdom.Element TMuebles = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element().createElement(nameSapceSap,"TMuebles");
    org.kxml2.kdom.Element item = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element().createElement(nameSapceSap,"item");

    org.kxml2.kdom.Element Zmueble = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element().createElement(nameSapceSap,"Zmueble");
    Zmueble.addChild(Node.TEXT,"");
    item.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,Zmueble);

    org.kxml2.kdom.Element Ztramo = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element().createElement(nameSapceSap,"Ztramo");
    Ztramo.addChild(Node.TEXT,"");
    item.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,Ztramo);

    org.kxml2.kdom.Element Znivel = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element().createElement(nameSapceSap,"Znivel");
    Znivel.addChild(Node.TEXT,"");
    item.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,Znivel);

    TMuebles.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,item);

    return TMuebles;
}
```

Should credentials be sent in a PropertyInfo object?
What is the correct way to sent the empty structure (TMuebles), in PropertyInfo object or org.kxml2.kdom.Element?

When I try to consume the WebService, the following exception appears:

06-05 17:28:37.647 27321-27426/com.example.android.examplewebservice W/System.err: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap-env:Server' faultstring: 'Web service processing error; more details in the web service error log on provider side (UTC timestamp 20170605230903; Transaction ID 593463DC6B5809C0E1008000AC1CFA8E)' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@13a02a98

What am I wrong?

Comment: looks like something went wrong on the web service end, that can be due to sending wrong data. Test the web service using this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah

Comment: @DarshanMiskin thank you by your comment. I try with the chrome extension, the response is "Success 200". Do you have any idea for what my code is wrong? I need to send a empty structure TMuebles, which I add with PropertyInfo, that is correct?

Comment: The way you are passing key-values looks fine. Check with the property names both on server end and the app end, they should be same. Also if you are using the plugin properly and it still throws error then surely the web service is to blame.

Comment: Also, since you are sending a structure its a little complicated. Instead send the structure as json string, it becomes real easy. Only one parameter has to be passed i.e the json and just parse the json at both ends